# Spring integration Object transformer based on Object Type

Tags: json, xml, spring, spring-integration

Spring integration has transformer to convert the payload to `JSON/XML`.
The problem is due to different services communicating through same `Messaging channel [AMQP]`.

I want to separate `JSON type payload` to one channel and `XML type payload` to another channel.

```
<amqp:inbound-channel-adapter channel="inputChannel" listener-container="messageListener"/>
<int:chain input-channel="inputChannel">
    <int:object-to-json-transformer object-mapper="jsonMapper" />
    <!--- based on payload type --->
    <tranformer ref="xmlMarshalUnmarshal" method="doTransform" />
</int:chain>
```

Any idea? I am using latest `Spring 4.1.x`

Comment: After transformation you want to separate channel for each ?

Comment: @SarfarazKhan      Push to different channels so that you can transform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that with the [Router](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html).

I'm not sure that `<int:payload-type-router>` helps here, because I'm sure that your AMQP adapter is based on the default `SimpleMessageConverter`, which returns `String` for body like your JSON or XML.

From other side need to know how the other AMQP side works (Producer). Does it populate `content-type` header for those specific messages?

Having that we can use `<header-value-router>`:

```
<header-value-router input-channel="inputChannel" header-name="contentType">
    <int:mapping value="text/json" channel="jsonTransformerChannel" />
    <int:mapping value="text/xml" channel="xmlTransformerChannel" />
</header-value-router>
```

From other side you always can convert your `body` already with the `<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter>` injecting `message-converter`.